# Display On-Screen Television Graphics During Live Broadcasts

Tags: graphics, live, television

How and with what software do major television companies display on-screen graphics during their programs?

For example:

> On ESPN, how do they produce the news
>   ticker on the bottom (both graphically
>   and from a source code point of view),
>   create and display the scores of
>   sports, and update and show selected
>   stats on the fly?

I've looked everywhere I can think of to find the answer, but I am at a loss.  That's where you guys (and girls) come in.  I hope you can help shed some light on this subject for me.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should invest some time on your search habits too, I guess :)

http://www.videodesignsoftware.com/products/newsticker.php
http://www.masternewmedia.org/video_internet_television/webcam-enhancer-utilities/webcam-video-mixer-overlay-camtwist-review-20070618.htm

Goodluck